# Read text from file skipping any spaces or empty lines

Tags: c, file

**Hi.
I need to read several files without spaces or empty lines between characters.They can have different layouts, such as 1.txt, 2.txt or 3.txt:**

---

*1.txt:*

```
t
h
i
s
f
i
l
e
```

*2.txt:*

```
l

i

k

e

t

h

a

t
```

*3.txt:*

```
s o m e t h i n g
l i k e 
t h a t
```

---

**How do i do that ? I Just have the following code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char c ;
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("1.txt","r");
    if(fp == NULL){
    puts("Open file failed\n");
    exit(-1);
    }

    while(fscanf(fp,"%c\n",&c)!=EOF){
        /*do things with c var*/
    }

    fclose(fp);
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) { if (isspace(c)) continue; ... }

Comment: don't use fscanf, use fgetc like kusma suggests.  Then have a check for whitespace (spaces, newlines, tabs ) and store or output if the character is ok

Comment: Like kusma suggested: use `fgetc`, and change the type of `c` to `int`, because that's what `fgetc` returns

Comment: Ok, thank you. It works like i wanted.

Comment: Other question..
And, in other case, if I have words instead of characters and I just have one word in a line? That is, words without empty lines between them.

Comment: @kusma can you help me again ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking how to read in a text file, ignoring spaces and empty lines. Please clarify your question so that we can help you better.

Here's something to get you started:

You could read in the entire file, then remove anything you don't want. The following post agrees with my experience that your application will probably run faster that way: 
[Reading a file faster in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851381/reading-a-file-faster-in-c)

If you agree with that approach, this next post will show you how to read the text file into a buffer, with some error handling:
[Reading the whole text file into a char array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747086/reading-the-whole-text-file-into-a-char-array-in-c)

Then you can use something like this to remove the spaces, and something similar for the extra new lines:
[Function to remove spaces from string/char array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13084236/function-to-remove-spaces-from-string-char-array-in-c)

I hope this helps get you started, and perhaps someone will find time today to post some code for you.

Comment: This question is solved. With a single char it works... Now, another question, similar to this but with words...if I have words instead of characters and I just have one word in a line? That is, words without empty lines between them.

Question link: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23498148/read-words-from-file-without-empty-lines-in-c)